# Scrapy and Google web scraping

Tags: mongodb, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to utilize scrapy to gather google search results and put them into MongoDB. However, I don't get any response... what am I missing?

It seems very simple.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.google.com/#q=site:www.linkedin.com%2Fpub+intext:(security+or+jsp)+and+(power+or+utility)',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div[1]/div/h3'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that the response does not have the elements you are requesting with XPath.

That's because you are seeing another site when using Scrapy and when using your browser. That's because when you call your `start_url` it loads Google and then an XHR request is sent to query the search.

Scrapy does not send this XHR call because such things are initiated by JavaScript which is not executed by Scrapy.

To see what scrapy gets when calling this URL and see if you find your expectations use Scrapy Shell:

```
scrapy shell "https://www.google.com/#q=site:www.linkedin.com%2Fpub+intext:(security+or+jsp)+and+(power+or+utility)"
```

Then when the command prompt appears you can see why you do not get results:

```
>>> response.xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div/div[1]/div/h3')
[]
>>>
```

So Scrapy finds nothing for your XPath because of the missing content.